# Exported from Chrome Extension of Talend API Collection and import into Postman is not working?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I have Exported  API Collection from Talend API Collection(chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm/index.html#requests) Chrome Extension for API Tested and try to import into Postman is not working?. Any one have idea how to make it work in postman

try to import the talend API Collection into POSTMAN tools . but its not working...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you exported a collection from the Talend API Tester tool, if so it's not possible to. The exports of the talend api tester only works within it share with other users or export then manually import it. You can import postman collections in it but not the other way.